# Using NODE_ENV with multiple environments in JavaScript projects

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, environment-variables

I work on many projects that run on Express servers, whether they are front-end (i.e. React.js) codebases or server-side `Node.js` `codebases`.

Many times with the front-end `codebases` I would load conditional configuration based on `NODE_ENV`, such as the URL of the restful API that the front-end makes requests to.

I many times also used NODE_ENV to conditionally load things like DB configuration for server-side `Node.js` projects.

On a project that consisted of development, staging, and production (3 environments), I would usually set up my code to load configuration based on the `NODE_ENV` being set to any one of those 3 environments (and maybe also "local").

I was recently working on a project that was referring to the production environment as "live."

When I decided to set the NODE_ENV=live for this environment, a coworker pointed out a major flaw with this approach.

It seems that Express and some other libraries for Node.js latch onto the fact that you will either be using "production" or "development" as your `NODE_ENV` and using other names for your environments can have unexpected effects.

**For example**, Express needs `NODE_ENV=production` in order to run in "production" mode.  According to the Express docs "Tests indicate that just doing this can improve app performance by a factor of three!"

Basically, I'm curious if it is considered common practice to set the `NODE_ENV` to values other than "development" and "production," like I've been doing in my projects.

I feel that if I'm going to deploy my code to the development or staging environments on the cloud, I don't think they should run in a different Express "mode" than the production environment.

Does it make more sense to maintain configurations separate from `NODE_ENV`?

**For example**, does it make sense to base your configuration off of a variable like `APP_ENV`, while ensuring that `NODE_ENV` is either "development" or "production" for `frameworks/packages` like Express.

Comment: I think a newer + better solution would be using `NODE_CONFIG_ENV`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58337435/2963579

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`NODE_ENV` is used to differentiate between development and production instances. It is not a good idea to run production code without `NODE_ENV=production`. `NODE_ENV=development` is usually not that important, because libraries usually just check to see if `NODE_ENV !== 'production'`. So if you want to have multiple production node environments, or production-like environments, each of them should set `NODE_ENV=production`. That said, you can definitely set other environment variables to whatever values you desire, and read them back from node at runtime.

A reasonable example would be to have a `local` `staging` and `production` versions of your configuration. In this case, I would recommend having `NODE_ENV` be just one of the parameters you set up for each environment. For instance, you might want three different databases for each of `local`, `staging` and `production` but set `NODE_ENV` to `development` on `local`, and `production` for both `staging` and `production`.

Since the variables will be shell variables, you will need a way of loading certain environment variables on the target operating system prior to running the server. Modules like https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv look promising for this purpose.

Comment: It seems you are suggesting that NODE_ENV should stick to either "development" or "production" and configuration can be loaded another way (i.e. adding a unique dotenv file to each of your project environments).  This makes sense, but I still feel like I see configuration based on NODE_ENV very often in the wild.  Take Loopback for example, https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Environment-specific-configuration.html#overview.  They mention in the docs, that you can use NODE_ENV=staging and set up a config.staging.json file.  I'm not saying this is correct, but it seems to be fairly prevalent.

Comment: It may exist in the wild, and it is probably effective for non-production environments, but because many libraries enable optimizations when `NODE_ENV` is set to `production`, you should make certain that you have that set for production environments.

Comment: @seansean11 are you looking for a different kind of answer? As far as best practices go, it is extremely unwise to not use `NODE_ENV=production` for many packages. I don't know if you are using them or not, but it is an industry best practice.

Comment: The answer is great.  I still can't believe that entire (popular) libraries are built around the idea that your config will load from the NODE_ENV https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config.  I'm sure many people using libraries like this set their NODE_ENV to values other than `development` or `production`, in order to accommodate environment specific configuration  and don't realize the implications.

Comment: I am curious to know that if I set `NODE_ENV=production` for actually non-production environments like QA, Stage, etc. where I have to run unit tests during CI/CD pipeline, will the unit test packages (Mocha, Jest, and Chai in my case) added as devdependencies will still be loaded in those environments?

Answer (score 24):

`NODE_ENV` should be set to either `development` or `production` in traditional sense.

The reason being, when you're building a front-end application (React, etc), you either build the application in `development` mode or `production` mode. For example, in `development` mode, you will watch for changes and build continuously. In production mode, you minify the code and optimize it for size.

In case of a node server, the `NODE_ENV` refers to what mode you start your application with. For example, in `development` mode, you configure your server and install all `devDependencies` and watch for changes and live reload the server. And in `production` mode, you only install `dependencies` and start the server with optimized configuration.

Now talking about different production environments, say `staging`, `pre-live`, `live`, etc, you should use a separate ENV variable for this. Except `local`, all other environments are considered `production` environments and your app should be built with and start in `production` mode in these environments.

You usually load different configurations, say api keys, urls for each environment. These should be differentiated with a separate ENV variable like `APP_ENV`.

I usually use `APP_ENV` to differentiate between `staging` and `live` environments.

This is how the `package.json` will look like with different start scripts for different environments

```
"scripts": {
  "start:local": "NODE_ENV=development APP_ENV=local your-start-script",
  "start:staging": "NODE_ENV=production APP_ENV=staging your-start-script",
  "start:live": "NODE_ENV=production APP_ENV=live your-start-script",
}
```

You will need to start the app with the right start script in each environment.

Comment: Above scripts are not working in case of Windows System? Any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NODE_ENV` for multiple environments when your install the `custom-env` module:
`npm install custom-env` 
Full docs here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-env